# State server in ubuntu

Tags: mono, ubuntu-12.04, session-state-server, xsp4

I deployed ASP.NET 4.0 website on ubuntu with apache2 and mono.

I want to use session state server for that i have to run `asp-state4` command in terminal so that state server will get started.

When i run above command all is working fine but after running command i have to keep that terminal open --

[image]

if i close that terminal state server will get stop and website won't work.

Is there any way to keep state server running in background, without keeping terminal open?

Comment: Have you had any luck getting an answer to this thread?

Answer (score 1):

For its source code, we can see that it was just designed that way,

https://github.com/mono/xsp/blob/master/tools/asp_state/asp_state.cs

As the source code is freely available, modify it as you wished.

Answer (score 0):

try screen command

```
screen -dmS aspstate asp-state
```